# Looking for format string which allows custom formatting for list of pairs

Tags: common-lisp

So I have lists, looking like this:

`((24 . 23) (9 . 6) ... )`

and want to custom format the output to something looking like this:

`"24/23 9/6 ..."`

I tried:

```
(defun show-pair (ostream pair col-used atsign-used) 
  (declare (ignore col-used atsign-used)) 
  (format ostream "~d/~d" (first pair) (second pair)))

(let ((x '( 1 . 2))) (format nil "~{~/show-pair/~^~}" (list x)))
```

as a simple warming up exercise to show a list with only 1 pair. But when trying this in the emacs slime repl, I get the error

> The value
> 2
> is not of type
> LIST
> [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

Which, of course is confusing as `~/show-pair/` was expected to handle one entry in the list, which is is the pair, passing the pair to `show-pair`. But it appears, something else is actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with `format` - the problem is to access first and second element of the alist using `format` directives. I didn't found how I could access them inside a `format` directive.

However, in such regularly formed structures like an alist, one could flatten the list first and then let `format`-looping directive consume two elements per looping - then one consumes the pair.

Since the famous `:alexandria` library doesn't count as dependency in Common Lisp world, one could directly use `alexandria:flatten`:

```
(defparameter *al* '((24 . 23) (9 . 6)))
(ql:quickload :alexandria) ;; import alexandria library

(format nil "~{~a/~a~^ ~}" (alexandria:flatten *al*))
;; => "24/23 9/6"
```

- `nil` return as string
- `~{ ~}` loop over the list
- `~a/~a` the fraction
- `~^`    empty space between the elements but not after last element

`flatten` by the way without `:alexandria`-"dependency" would be in this case:

```
(defun flatten (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((atom l) (list l))
        (t (append (flatten (car l)) (flatten (cdr l))))))
```

Comment: Yes, this is an idea I also considered, but my real data has sometimes more than 2 elements and sometimes numbers and sometimes symbols in some places. So, I pursued the `~/.../` approach as the function called is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for feedback, I found out, where the problem is coming from:

So far, I considered `(second x)` to behave exactly like `(cdr x)` but for tagged values, this assumption is wrong. If I change in `show-pairs` above (in the question) accordingly, it all works.

So, it is not a formatting problem at all, nor any surprises with how `~/foo~/` works.

```
(defun show-pair (ostream pair col-used atsign-used) 
  (declare (ignore col-used atsign-used)) 
  (format ostream "~d/~d" (first pair) (cdr pair))) ;; second -> cdr fixes the problem
```

Comment: `second` never behaves like `cdr`; [it behaves like `cadr`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm)

Comment: The `cdr` synonym is `rest`.

Comment: Silly mistakes like this happen, whenever one uses other, new thing and focuses on those (like me using this way of formatting for the first time).

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly seldom a good idea to use `~/.../` in `format` in my experience.  It's probably much better to simply turn the list you have into the list you need and then process that directly.  So, for instance:

```
> (format t "~&~:{~D/~D~:^, ~}~%"
        (mapcar (lambda (p)
                  (list (car p) (cdr p)))
                '((1 . 2) (3 . 4))))
1/2, 3/4
nil
```

Or if you want to use `loop`:

```
 > (format t "~&~:{~D/~D~:^, ~}.~%"
        (loop for (n . d) in '((1 . 2) (3 . 4))
              collect (list n d)))
1/2, 3/4.
nil
```

The cost (and storage) associated with converting the list is likely to be absolutely tiny compared with the I/O cost of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using hints from [Redefinition of the print-object method for conses...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907161/redefinition-of-the-print-object-method-for-conses-has-different-effects-in-diff/31908258#31908258), you could end up with something like this:

```
CL-USER> (let ((std-function (pprint-dispatch 'cons)))
           (unwind-protect 
                (progn (set-pprint-dispatch 
                        'cons 
                        (lambda (s o) (format s "~d/~d" (car o) (cdr o))))
                       (format t "~{~a~%~}" '((23 . 24) (5 . 9))))
             (set-pprint-dispatch 'cons std-function))
           (format t "~{~a~%~}" '((23 . 24) (5 . 9))))
23/24
5/9
(23 . 24)
(5 . 9)
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Hiding the bookkeeping;

```
(defmacro with-fractional-conses (&body body)
  (let ((std-function (gensym "std-function")))
    `(let ((,std-function (pprint-dispatch 'cons)))
       (unwind-protect 
            (progn (set-pprint-dispatch 
                    'cons 
                    (lambda (s o) (format s "~d/~d" 
                                          (car o) 
                                          (cdr o))))
                   ,@body)
         (set-pprint-dispatch 'cons ,std-function)))))


CL-USER> (with-fractional-conses 
           (format t "~{~a~%~}" 
                   '((23 . 24) (5 . 9))))
23/24
5/9
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Comment: This (v1) is a fairly dangerous approach because it's essentially shallow-binding the dispatch table (really: it's shallow-binding entries in the table), and shallow-binding is very hard to make thread-safe and certainly would not be in this case.  A better approach is to make a copy of the table and then explicitly bind `*print-pprint-dispatch*` to that copy.  This is a clever trick however!