# Reading hash table from file fails

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I wrote a custom reader macro for printing hash tables:

```
#| Custom printer for hash tables |#

;; object = hash table
;; stream = output stream
(defmethod print-object ((object hash-table) stream)
  (format stream "#H(~{~{(~S . ~S)~}~^ ~})"
          (loop for key being the hash-keys of object
                  using (hash-value value)
                collect (list key value))))

(defun hash-reader (stream char n)
  (declare (ignore char n))
  (let* ((body (read stream t nil t)))
    (loop
      with hash = (make-hash-table :test #'equal)
      for (key . val) in body do
        (setf (gethash key hash) val)
      finally (return hash))))

(set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\H #'hash-reader)
```

I have a program that embeds hash tables inside a tree structure and prints out the tree to a file. Later, I want to read the tree from a file, but I get the following error:

```
Error (SIMPLE-ERROR) during printing: #<SIMPLE-ERROR {1020C9DA73}>
```

To be honest, I'm not very familiar with reader macros, and I'm not entirely sure what is wrong here. I believe the error has to do with the fact that `*print-circle*` is set to `t`. It appears that the reader is able to read the hash tables, at least initially, then for some reason it can't any more.

Code to reproduce:

```
(defun read-from-file (fname)
  (with-open-file (s fname)
    (read s)))

(defun save-to-file(content fname)
  (with-open-file (s fname
             :direction :output
             :if-exists :supersede
             :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (format s "~S" content)))

(defun generate-list()
  (loop
    with hash
    with prev = nil
    for i from 1 to 1000
    do
       (setq hash (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
       (setf (gethash i hash) i)
       (setq prev (cons (cons hash prev) prev))
    finally
       (return prev)))

(save-to-file (generate-list) "file.txt")
(read-from-file "file.txt")
```

Comment: The link to your file is returning _403: Access Denied_. You should include a minimal example of data directly in your question, along with any other code you need to reproduce the issue. See [mcve].

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908258/124319, may be better to not rely on print-object being able to be specialized for standard types

Comment: See also rutils' `#h(` reader macro and Serapeum's `dict` with its `toggle-pretty-print-hash-table`. https://github.com/vseloved/rutils/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md & https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md (where its pretty print isn't done with print-object)

Comment: @adabsurdum I have added a minimum example. Sorry it took so much time for me to respond. Things just got busy a bit for me. Please have a look when you have a chance

Comment: @coredump I have added a miminum example, please have look

Comment: @Ehvince I have added a miminum example, please have look

Comment: I don't understand why you need to put `prev` both in the head of the new `prev` and in the cons, I tried with 3 instead of 1000 and with print-circle being T, this doesn't look like something I would ever need to do, just collecting the list of hashes would work

Comment: @coredump thanks for pointing that out. I suppose, the issue is that this minimal example is just a toy example. The point I was trying to make is that I have a circlular list, so technically the structure is infinite. In such cases, it seems that this causes a problem in the reader and I cannot resolve this issue.